# openpyxl+load_workbook+AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date1904'

Tags: openpyxl, attributeerror, nonetype

When I use openpyxl to load the Excel file( .xlsx), this error displays (the last the link is the sample Excel file):

> from openpyxl import *
>   wb = load_workbook("D:/develop/workspace/exman/test sample/510001653.xlsx")
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\
>   xcel.py", line 161, in load_workbook
>
> parser.parse()
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\packagi
>   g\workbook.py", line 42, in parse
>
> if package.properties.date1904:
>
> **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date1904'**

[sample excel file download](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HBb4b2jCcZ0Nm8Yp29Hzl6R4jRBFW3sCHMSsKTtib9c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sorry ,the up link file after  'save as ' by google doc, there will be no this error. So I re-upload the excel file to baidu cloud. the link is: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1slOUVDF

Comment: Why are you using the pre-development version of openpyxl?

Comment: I want to use the copy_worksheet(), only pre version has. But I use the version 2.3.5, the error still exist.

Comment: 2.5 has never been released not even as a pre-release. Use a checkout of 2.4

Comment: I change the openpyxl from 2.5 to 2.4b1 to 2.3.5, the error is same. You can test my sample xlsx file. The error happens on load_workbook().

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote and use a checkout.

Comment: Debug the python file , I find that reason :1 workbookPr = None , cause the properties is None, 2 the childSheet and properties is under the bookviews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I debug the python file ,and find that the workbookPr = None , cause the package.properties to None( properties = Alias(workbookPr). So I change  the  code of workbookParser.parser() like follow, the error is solved.

```
class WorkbookParser:

def __init__(self, archive):
    self.archive = archive
    self.wb = Workbook()
    self.sheets = []
    self.rels = get_dependents(self.archive, ARC_WORKBOOK_RELS)


def parse(self):
    src = self.archive.read(ARC_WORKBOOK)
    node = fromstring(src)
    package = WorkbookPackage.from_tree(node)

    if package.properties is not None: #add this line 
        if package.properties.date1904:
            wb.excel_base_date = CALENDAR_MAC_1904
        self.wb.code_name = package.properties.codeName
   self.wb.active = package.active
```

..........

Comment: I needed this today, thanks!  I suppose it should be reported to openpyxl?

Comment: Hello  Ben, Thank you for your advice. I have add a issue on the official web- bitbucket : https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/739/openpyxl-load_workbook-attributeerror

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in newer versions (I checked 2.4.8 and its fixed. 2.4.0 still had it)

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl
```